# WordPress Wufoo PHP not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, forms

So, I am an extremely novice coder for my company. I have been having difficulty getting our Wufoo form to pre-fill data from a previous entry to make it easier for our users to submit multiple times without wasting their time by tediously filling in the whole form multiple times.
Below is the code I am putting into the page;

```
<div id="wufoo-z1ikc4gj032y2rv">
Fill out my <a href="https://shoppingtoeducate.wufoo.com/forms/z1ikc4gj032y2rv">online form</a>.
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">var z1ikc4gj032y2rv;(function(d, t) {
var s = d.createElement(t), options = {
'userName':'shoppingtoeducate',
'formHash':'z1ikc4gj032y2rv',
'autoResize':true,
'defaultValues':'field9=<?php echo $_GET["field9"]; ?>&field10=<?php echo $_GET["field10"]; ?>&field12=<?php echo $_GET["field12"]; ?',
'height':'2201',
'async':true,
'host':'wufoo.com',
'header':'show',
'ssl':true};
s.src = ('https:' == d.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'www.wufoo.com/scripts/embed/form.js';
s.onload = s.onreadystatechange = function() {
var rs = this.readyState; if (rs) if (rs != 'complete') if (rs != 'loaded') return;
try { z1ikc4gj032y2rv = new WufooForm();z1ikc4gj032y2rv.initialize(options);z1ikc4gj032y2rv.display(); } catch (e) {}};
var scr = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0], par = scr.parentNode; par.insertBefore(s, scr);
})(document, 'script');</script>
```

I do realize I did slightly deviate from Wufoo's tutorial on how to pre-fill forms from here;

https://www.wufoo.com/guides/multiple-form-submissions-with-prefilled-fields/

By having the `&lt;` replaced by <   , but shouldn't that be the same thing and not make a difference?
I have also tried it by replacing all < signs with `&lt;` as well as having > replaced with `&gt;` or just > replaced with `&gt;` just to see if it mattered.
The URL after the user submits their data is feeding back the right stuff, it usually comes out like this

www.domain.com/form/?field9=John&field10=Lannister&field12=example@example.com

it does put in the right data within the URL, but the code is not pulling it back out and feeding it into the form.
Any help would be greatly appreciated; however, I am a novice, so please don't kill me haha.

The page I am working on can be found at the following URL:

https://www.shoplakecrestvillage.com/submit-reciepts

EDIT: I am really hoping for some help on this, Wufoo refused to help me in any way and says they cannot help me (even though I literally copied their guide on this). My boss is starting to crawl up on me about this.

Comment: Why is everyone down voting this post? I admitted I am a novice coder, but I did my best to solve the problem I had before asking for help here. I showed all the resources I used and properly referenced them along with where the code itself is being used. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately, my boss got all over me and I was forced to just use the default Wufoo page and their API to save the user data. She wants me to remove the embedded pages unless I can get the user info to save within the next couple days. If anyone could help me out, that would be great.